# Error for using RecycleView with support-v4:23.4.0 for CollapsingToolbarLayout app Creash

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have used a RecyclerView with `support-v4:23.4.0` for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The app crashes when I scroll `RecyclerView`. If I remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'` it works properly but I get this exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMatrix(Landroid/view       /View;)Landroid/graphics/Matrix; in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/data/com.awakens.wordbite/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_c149b670e0a79dbcc1eb126d08230366b4cd28ab-classes.dex)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.getTransformedBoundingBox(RecyclerView.java:8042)
```

Build File

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':library')
compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude module: "fastadapter"
}
compile project(path: ':TabPagerLibrary')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.3.2@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:0.3.0@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.+'

compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}

}
```

Comment: what you want to say

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: Error for scroll RecyclerView No static method getMatrix(Landroid/view/View;)

Comment: its not clear , please show something some code , error stack so that we can help you out

Comment: please post some code..have you added layout manager to your recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

just remove the following

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}
```

and check , and then let us know

Comment: When i remove compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}   error for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: When i remove                                                                                  compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}    get Error : Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: then remove compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0' the third last line from your code

Answer (score 0):

you just add dependence

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the appcompat library.
Just add this lib:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

keep support v4 lib like this:

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}
```

Remove this v4 lib:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

you need to keep one line which is work with your CollapsingToolbarLayout.